# Is there anyway to determine which buttons to use to take a screenshot?

Tags: android, android-emulator, screenshot

Does anyone know a way to detect which buttons to press in order to take screen shots in android devices ?

for eg.

Samsung (Power button + Volume Down)

Answer (score 0):

**Power button + vol down** works for 99% of android devices. However, every manufacturer decides on his own, which buttons to use. Sometimes it can be **power + vol up** or **home (if it is physical) + power**